# Why is the class not accessible in unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have created a unit test for a method in a class called **game.cs**. For some reason, when I reference the class, I am unable to create a new instance. How do I make this class accessible so I can test my code?

File Hierarchy and solution:

[image]

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using BowlingKataTDD;

namespace BowlingKataTDDTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class BowlingKataTDDUnitTests 
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void DoesGameExist()
        {
            //arrange
            BowlingKataTDD.
        }
    }
}
```

BowlingKataTDD Project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BowlingKataTDD
{
    class Game
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you do not see the classes is that they are non-public (internal by default).

There are two solutions to this:

- If you would like to make your classes visible to outside users, make them `public`
- If you would rather not publish your classes, [use `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt632254.aspx).

To use the second solution, open `AssemblyInfo.cs` and add the following line:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("BowlingKataTDDTest")]
```

`BowlingKataTDDTest` is the name of your assembly, as defined in the project file.

Comment: How do I use the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute, is that a class modifier?

Comment: @JDavila This trick is very useful for testing classes and methods that you would rather not make public.

Comment: Good to know, that will be so helpful, when testing, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Make the class `public`, as well as any members of that class which need to be invoked externally (such as by a unit test):

```
public class Game
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common mistake with calling libraries with new projects, and I was able to resolve it. Often easy to forget to change the modifier to public from the project in Visual Studio, because by default a new project template creates the class though without it being set to public. When changing the Game class to public, am able to instantiate the Game object.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using BowlingKataTDD;

namespace BowlingKataTDDTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class BowlingKataTDDUnitTests 
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void DoesGameExist()
        {
            //arrange
            BowlingKataTDD.Game game = new BowlingKataTDD.Game();
        }
    }
}
```